# C++ Strip non-ASCII Characters from string

Tags: c++, string, ascii

Before you get started; yes I know this is a duplicate question and yes I have looked at the posted solutions. My problem is I could not get them to work.

```
bool invalidChar (char c)
{ 
    return !isprint((unsigned)c); 
}
void stripUnicode(string & str)
{
    str.erase(remove_if(str.begin(),str.end(), invalidChar), str.end()); 
}
```

I tested this method on "Prusæus, Ægyptians," and it did nothing
I also attempted to substitute `isprint` for `isalnum`

The real problem occurs when, in another section of my program I convert string->wstring->string. the conversion balks if there are unicode chars in the string->wstring conversion.

Ref:

[How can you strip non-ASCII characters from a string? (in C#)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/123336/how-can-you-strip-non-ascii-characters-from-a-string-in-c)

[How to strip all non alphanumeric characters from a string in c++?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6319872/how-to-strip-all-non-alphanumeric-characters-from-a-string-in-c)

**Edit:**

I still would like to remove all non-ASCII chars regardless yet if it helps, here is where I am crashing:

```
// Convert to wstring
wchar_t* UnicodeTextBuffer = new wchar_t[ANSIWord.length()+1];
wmemset(UnicodeTextBuffer, 0, ANSIWord.length()+1);
mbstowcs(UnicodeTextBuffer, ANSIWord.c_str(), ANSIWord.length());
wWord = UnicodeTextBuffer; //CRASH
```

**Error Dialog**

MSVC++ Debug Library

Debug Assertion Failed!

Program: //myproject

File: f:\dd\vctools\crt_bld\self_x86\crt\src\isctype.c

Line: //Above

Expression:(unsigned)(c+1)<=256

**Edit:**

Further compounding the matter: the .txt file I am reading in from is ANSI encoded. Everything within *should* be valid.

**Solution:**

```
bool invalidChar (char c) 
{  
    return !(c>=0 && c <128);   
} 
void stripUnicode(string & str) 
{ 
    str.erase(remove_if(str.begin(),str.end(), invalidChar), str.end());  
}
```

If someone else would like to copy/paste this, I can check this question off.

**EDIT:**

For future reference: try using the [__isascii, iswascii](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/5wcd48xw.aspx) commands

Comment: What happens if you change invalidChar to always return true and what happens when it's always false. Additionally log what ivalidChar gets and it's output.

Comment: @Dani On it... (more chars to post)

Comment: Make sure you call `setlocale("");` before you do the conversion. There's no point in a conversion if it can't handle non-ASCII characters, is there!

Comment: @ Dani setting invalidChar to `return true` kicks out a blank string while `false` does nothing. I too suspected that to be the problem yet I am unsure what method to use other that `isprint` and `isalnum` as they do not seem to be getting the job done.

Comment: @KerrekSB I have this: `setlocale(LC_ALL, ""); ` a few lines further down than the line that throws an error. I use it for converting wstring->string. Are you saying I should move that up a few lines?

Comment: Yes, it must be the first thing in your program!

Comment: Is your environment's locale set to something useful? Try a few of the popular ones (`ISO-8859-15`, `UTF-8`).

Comment: @KerrekSB To be frank, I am not that familiar with what `setlocale` actually does. I'll try putting 'setlocale(LC_ALL, "ISO-8859-15");` into the first line of `main`

Comment: @KerrekSB I may be doing it wrong but neither the above nor `setlocale(LC_ALL, "UTF-8");` ahd any effect.

Comment: If you leave the `""` in, you can just set the locale in your shell: `LC_ALL=en_GB.utf8 ./myprog`

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Solution:

```
bool invalidChar (char c) 
{  
    return !(c>=0 && c <128);   
} 
void stripUnicode(string & str) 
{ 
    str.erase(remove_if(str.begin(),str.end(), invalidChar), str.end());  
}
```

EDIT:

For future reference: try using the __isascii, iswascii commands

Comment: Shouldn't this be `unsigned char` instead of `char`? a regular `char` will always be < 128...
```
#include <iostream>
int main(){
        char c = 129;
        std::cout << (c<128) << "\n";
        return 0;
}```

Answer (score 2):

At least one problem is in your `invalidChar` function.  It should be:

```
return !isprint( static_cast<unsigned char>( c ) );
```

Casting a `char` to an `unsigned` is likely to give some very, very big
values if the `char` is negative (`UNIT_MAX+1 + c).  Passing such a
value to`isprint` is undefined behavior.

Comment: switching the method as prescribed fixes `Prusæus` but not `Ægyptians` which still causes a crash.

Comment: @AnthonyW If `c` has type `char`, and you're on an Intel platform, then casting it to `unsigned char` before calling `isprint` should make that part of the code work.  Of course, there is still the problem as to what you mean by ASCII; the definition I'd use is `c >= 0 && c < 128` (but this includes non-printable ASCII like EOT or DEL).

Comment: Yes, that is the char set I am looking for. Unless I am mistaken `Æ` is not a member, yet it refuses to be removed. Of couse, I could be mistaken in which case I need a different approach.

Comment: Switched statement to `return !(c>=0 && c <128); ` <-- this removes it. Apparently `Æ` is Extended ASCII Character 146 and falls into the system's check for `<256`. However, even with that the case, that does not explain the Error Dialog above which claimes `Æ` is outside the range.

Comment: There must be 2 versions of that char as even with a check for `<256` it is removed.

Comment: @AnthonyW For the 95 printable ASCII, and the 33 control characters, the 
encoding is more or less universal (except for EBCDIC on the
mainframes); all of the usual encodings use the same codes, in the range
0...127.  For anything else (and thus for `æ` and `Æ`), the actual value
will depend on the encoding; the value won't be the same in latin 1 as
in UTF-8, for example (and in UTF-8, they will use a multibyte
encoding).  What `isprint` does with them will depend on the locale.

Comment: @AnthonyW With regards to a possible error: if `char` is signed, then it can't contain 146; if you convert it to `int`, the results will be -110.  Calling `isprint` with a negative number (other than `EOF`, probably -1) is undefined behavior.  Casting it to `unsigned char` results in the -110 being converted to 146, and the following conversion to `int` should preserve this value.  What `isprint` returns when passed 146 will depend on the locale, but it should **not** crash.

Answer (score 1):

`isprint` depends on the locale, so the character in question must be printable in the current locale.

If you want strictly ASCII, check the range for [0..127].  If you want printable ASCII, check the range and `isprint`.

Answer (score 1):

Another solution that doesn't require defining two functions but uses anonymous functions available in C++17 above:

```
void stripUnicode(string & str) 
{ 
    str.erase(remove_if(str.begin(),str.end(), [](char c){return !(c>=0 && c <128);}), str.end());  
}
```

I think it looks cleaner