# Palindrome finder: non-alphanumeric character deletion problems

Tags: c++, palindrome

So I'm having a substantial amount of trouble with this one bit of code.  I've included the whole program for context, but my issue lies in the cleanUp function, wherein I (attempt to) remove all characters that are not 'A' through 'Z'.

Any tips?

```
#include <iostream>
#include <cstdlib>
#include <string>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <ctype.h>

using namespace std;

bool again(string title);               // Checks if you want to run again.
void makeUpper(char word[]);
void getReverse(char word[], char reversed[]);
char * find(char *str, char what);
bool equal(char word[], char reversed[]);
int size(char word[]);
char * cleanUp(char *str);

int main()
{
    char word[256] = "Hello?? There!", reversedWord[256];
    do
    {
        cout<<"Please enter the string to check: ";
        makeUpper(word);
        cout << word;
        cleanUp(word);
        getReverse(word,reversedWord);
        if(equal(word, reversedWord))
            cout<<"You have a palindrome!"<<endl;
        else
            cout<<"You do not have a palindrome!"<<endl;

    } while(again("Do you want to do this again? "));
    return 0;
}

bool again(string title)
{
    string answer;
    cout<<endl<<title;
    getline(cin,answer);
    return toupper(answer[0]) == 'Y';
}


void makeUpper(char word[])
{
    char *ptr = word;
    while (*ptr) {
        *ptr = toupper(*ptr);
        ptr++;
    }
    cout << "In uppercase:: " << word << endl;
}

char * cleanUp(char * astrid)
{
    char *new_astrid;
    for (*astrid; *astrid != '\0'; astrid++)
    {
        cout << "First loop";
        if (isalpha(*astrid))
        {
            *new_astrid = *astrid;
            new_astrid = ++new_astrid;
            cout << "Here!";
        }
    }
    cout << *new_astrid;
    return *new_astrid;
}



void getReverse(char word[], char reversed[])
{
    char *ptr_ind = find(word, '\0'), *ptr_ind_2 = reversed;
    while(ptr_ind != word-1)
    {
        *ptr_ind_2 = *ptr_ind;
        ptr_ind--;
        ptr_ind_2++;
    }
    *ptr_ind_2 = '\0';
}

char * find(char *str, char what)
{
    char *ptr = str;
    while(*ptr != what && *ptr != '\0')
        ptr++;
    return *ptr == what ? ptr : NULL;
}

bool equal(char word[], char reverse[])
{
    int total;
    char * ptr;
    ptr = word;
    if((total = size(word)) != size(reverse))
        return false;
    for(char * ptr2 = reverse;  *ptr != '\0' && *ptr == *ptr2; ptr++, ptr2++);
    return *ptr == '\0';
}

int size(char word[])
{
    int total = 0;
    char * ptr = word;
    while(*ptr != '\0')        //while(!ptr)
    {
        ptr++;
        total++;
    }
    return total;
}
```

Comment: What problems are you seeing?

Comment: One problem would definitely be that you dereference new_astrid before you initialize it.

Comment: When removing an item in an array (of char or any other) you need to shift all the following items towards the beginning of the array. Any reason you are not using string by the way?

Answer (score 1):

There are several errors in your code.

`new_astrid` is not initialized and when you call `*new_astrid = *astrid` you try to copy a character to uninitialized memory, which will crash the program.
You also return the dereferenced pointer to `new_astrid` but the function prototype of `cleanUp` says that you return a `pointer to char`.

You should initialize `new_astrid` with `new char[strlen(astrid)]`. But then your code will result in memory leaks, since you increase the pointer (`new_astid = ++new_astrid`). So you should store the pointer first, so you can delete it later.

Instead of using raw pointers, i would suggest you use `std::strings`.

My suggestion for a palindrome tester would be:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <locale>

bool isPalindrome(std::string word)
{
    std::locale loc;
    for (std::string::size_type i = 0; i < word.length() / 2 + 1; ++i)
    {
        if (std::toupper(word[i],loc) != std::toupper(word[word.length() - i - 1],loc))
        {
            return false;
        }
    }

    return true;
}

int main(int , char **)
{
    std::string str = "Abba";

    //Remove all non alpha values from string
    str.erase(std::remove_if(str.begin(), str.end(), [](char const c){return !std::isalpha(c);}), str.end());

    if (isPalindrome(str) == false)
    {
        std::cout << str << " is no palindrome" << std::endl;
    }
    else 
    {
        std::cout << str << " is a palindrome" << std::endl;
    }

    return 0;
}
```

The erasion of non alpha values in the string is from [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6319872/how-to-strip-all-non-alphanumeric-characters-from-a-string-in-c) question.